# Oracle - Is it possible for the results of a transaction not to be visible to a subsequent transaction?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, transaction, jdbc

We're having a strange problem with a flaky integration test. This is using Java/JDBC against an Oracle 12 database. The test does this, in pseudocode:

```
transaction 1 {
    insert into order (id, cancelled) values (123, 0)
    insert into report (id, cancelled) values (234, 0)
    commit
}

transaction 2 {
    update order set cancelled = 1 where id = 123
    update report set cancelled = 1 where id = 234
    commit
}

transaction 3 {
    select cancelled from order where id = 123
    if cancelled <> 1 then fail test
}

transaction 4 {
    select cancelled from report where id = 234
    # this check sometimes fails:
    if cancelled <> 1 then fail test
}
```

All of that one by one in this order, on the same thread. The test usually succeeds, but sometimes (once in 10 to 20 runs) it fails on the last check.

Note that when this happens a manual database inspection reveals that the value of cancelled is in fact 1, so the problem is not that the code has malfunctioned; the problem is that transaction 4 is somehow not seeing that new value.

One theory I'm looking into is that somehow transaction 3 is already seeing the results of transaction 2, but transaction 4 is not. Is that possible? At what point are the results of a transaction guaranteed to be available to subsequent transactions? We use connection pooling; what if transaction 4 uses a different connection? What are other directions we could investigate for this occasional test failure?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is, does your "pseudo-code" automatically commit the transactions or are do you manually commit the transcations? What happens when errors occur (think: error-handling)?

Comment: @hot2use Yes, we use automatic transaction management and transaction 1 is committed before transaction 2 is started. Actually we don't start transactions for 2 and 3, but if I understood correctly that just means the statement is executed in an implicit transaction, right?

Comment: @PepijnSchmitz - I'm unaware of any "Automatic Transaction Management" outside of an explicit `dbh.commit()` or `autocommit = true`.  Can you post URL to this definition?  (You might need to post actual code, not pseudo code.)

Comment: I think the answer is no, this is not possible. But maybe the code does not behave as you describe in your pseudocode or there are additional transaction you are not aware of.

Comment: @MichaelKutz We use Spring's transaction manager support. The code for the first transaction is in a method annotated with @ Transactional, which starts a transaction upon entering the method and commits it upon successfully leaving it. Posting the real code is unfortunately not feasible due to its size and confidentiality.

I'm mainly interested in learning if it is in theory possible for one transaction to see the results of a previous one, and for a subsequent transaction *not* to see those results. For example if they happen in very quick succession, or on a different connection.

Comment: @miracle173 Always possible of course, although we put a lot of time into it already to eliminate other factors and we're pretty confident this is accurate.

Comment: we do not see how rows with cancelled!=1 get into the table. If during transaction1 such a row is inserted it will not be updated by transaction1 and transaction2 or 3 will fail the test.

Comment: you can use logminer to analyze your transactions if you have the appropriate permissions or you can add triggers to the tables that log the udate/insert activity (at least if it is a dev database)

Comment: @miracle173 Good point. The rows have been inserted earlier with cancelled == 0. I'll add that to the pseudocode for clarity. I should also add that if we manually look in the database after this test fails, the value of cancelled is in fact 1. So the problem is not in the code under test; it is updating the value and committing the transaction, yet the check at end still sees cancelled == 0.

Comment: Does tran 3 commit before tran 4 is started?

Comment: Here is the documentation of the  [Spring Transaction Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) but at the moment I am not willing to read it. If in Oracle there are four transactions in series and a transaction starts and ends before the next starts then there is no concurrency and a transaction sees the results of all the previous transactions. So if the program behaves in the way you describe then the transaction s are not as your pseudocode indicates, e.g they do not start or end at where you indicate.

Comment: @miracle173 Thanks, I guess that answers my question and I should dive deeper into whether this really is where the transactions happen.